# How can I select first inserted row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

may be this question be unrelated to stackoverflow . but this is my problem and i do not know the syntax . 
with this query i select the persons who had transactions by their date time .
this is my query 
[image: Selecting People who had transactions]

i want to write query that select the their first TransactionsTimeStamp?

Comment: Do you want only the first transaction `timestamp ` then you can use `TOP` with your query

Comment: Post sample-data, the query and the table schema, not images.

Comment: I know that i can use top. but top bring me only 1 record . i want  all people

Comment: So you want all the peoples first transaction `timestamp` correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for ranking functions like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), you could use them for example with a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ..., RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName 
                                        ORDER BY TransactionsTimeStamp ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName ... (join tables here)
)
SELECT ....
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

`...` are the columns that you want to select, you can select all, as opposed to a `GROUP BY`.

But if you just want to select the `TransactionsTimeStamp`-column for every user:

```
SELECT MIN(TransactionsTimeStamp) AS TransactionsTimeStamp, FirstName, LastName 
FROM dbo.tableName   ... (join tables here)
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: @salar: why do you want to use something different? I thought that you want to get the first record according to the `TransactionsTimeStamp`-column for every `FirstName, LastName`-group. At least that is what the query above does.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter your code is perfect , but i tried  your code and i have error

Comment: @salar: note that i've edited my answer to provide a simple `GROUP BY` which is better if you just want to select the `MIN(TransactionsTimeStamp)` for every user. **Edit** I see that the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28040803/284240) has already showed that.

Comment: Thank You very much sir , I tried your code and i get my query .

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your query is that you are grouping by Date column. So you are getting all different Date values as a result. You should group only by FirstName and LastName and apply some aggregation functions to Date column.

If just Min date is needed then you can get that date using aggregate function like:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
    (
      first_name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      last_name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      transaction_date DATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO @test
VALUES  ( 'A', 'B', '20150101' )
INSERT  INTO @test
VALUES  ( 'A', 'B', '20150120' )
INSERT  INTO @test
VALUES  ( 'C', 'D', '20150103' )
INSERT  INTO @test
VALUES  ( 'C', 'D', '20150119' )



SELECT  first_name ,
        last_name ,
        MIN(transaction_date) AS min_transaction_date
FROM    @test
GROUP BY first_name ,
        last_name
```

Output:

```
first_name  last_name   min_transaction_date
A   B   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
C   D   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select firstname, lastname, min(date) as minimum_date from clubprofile_cp
group by firstname, lastname
```